# jQuery 1.7 to 1.4

Tags: jquery, drupal, migration, jquery-1.4, jquery-1.7

i'm working with drupal and the current version of jQuery for drupal is the 1.4, but in the current HTML the developer used the ON(). function, how can i adapt this for 1.4?

```
$('body').on('click.button.data-api', '[data-toggle^=button]', function (e) {
                var $btn = $(e.target)
                if (!$btn.hasClass('btn')) $btn = $btn.closest('.btn')
                $btn.button('toggle')
```

Comment: And all Lego bricks are compatible since 60's...

Comment: Please remember to mark a response as an answer if it helped you, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery 1.3 used 'live', before being superseeded by on http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Taken from the first paragraph of your link: "Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()." - I'd suggest using `.delegate()` if it's supported in 1.4, but I don't know if it'd make much of a change. Probably not. Edit: `.delegate` is supported in version 1.4.2+.

Comment: Yup that's the reason why I didn't suggest delegate, I assumed he was using 1.4, but good catch :)

Comment: I see, +1 as your solution is suitable for both cases. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked into the `.bind('click')` event?

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

`$('#foo').bind('click', function() {
  alert('User clicked on "foo."');
});`